# Sorting date boundfield on gridview didn't work

Tags: sorting, gridview

this is my code to sort date boundfield on gridview having AllowSorting = True

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="VisitDate" HeaderText="Visit Date" DataFormatString="{0:MM/dd/yyyy}" SortExpression="VisitDate"/>

 protected void grdDocuments_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
        {

            switch (e.SortExpression)
            {
                case "VisitDate":

                    if (e.SortExpression != grdDocuments.SortExpression)
                    {
                        e.SortDirection = SortDirection.Descending;
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
```

but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Use this given code or follow the link and see demo for sorting date in bound field of a gridview:

```
string sortExpression = e.SortExpression;
        ViewState["SortExpression"] = sortExpression;

        if (GridViewSortDirection == SortDirection.Ascending)
        {
            GridViewSortDirection = SortDirection.Descending;
            SortGridView(sortExpression, DESCENDING);
        }
        else
        {
            GridViewSortDirection = SortDirection.Ascending;
            SortGridView(sortExpression, ASCENDING);
        }
```

Demo Link here: [Sorting Date Demo](http://www.nullskull.com/a/866/aspnet--sorting-a-gridview-bound-to-a-custom-data-object.aspx)